# How do I create a view in iOS 5 which can scroll in any direction, like a map?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

How do I build a freely scrollable view on iOS 5? I mean, I need to build a view which can scroll from left-right and top-down (any direction) and it will stay there. Inside this view, I need to place different kinds of objects.

(Imagine scrolling like a map. - I am using Storyboard.)

Comment: What's the difference between a UIScrollView and what you want?

Comment: I tried using a UIScrollView, but the objects placed at the top always stay at the top. I played with the "bounces", etc. settings and that was what happened - it always stay on top (the positions of the top objects are fixed.) I need it scroll freely like a map.

Comment: I've just seen your comment check my edit, under.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, UIScrollView.

And don't forget to set the content size !! (every noobs - including me - are always asking the same question, *why my scrollView does not work?*)

=> `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 2000)]`, for example.

**EDIT :**

I just saw your comment. I don't understand what you call "on top".

I made an app with custom maps, and I used an UIScrollView to make the job: it was pretty good at it.

You just have to add each scrollable element as **subviews** of your UIScrollView. And set the **contentSize** to fit to the subviews' frames, of course.

Comment: I mean objects placed at the top-left are always staying at the top-left - even after I scrolled it and it bounces back to the top-left position.

Comment: I'm going to try setting the size and see what happens.

Comment: do you want infinite scroll ? If so what do you display after your last element ? If so again, you should set the contentSize dynamically

Comment: OK. I changed the UIView into UIScrollView and set the content size, and it worked! Thanks!